# BigQuery multiple rows update in a single job

Tags: node.js, google-bigquery, gcloud

I have two arrays one is for values I want to update and one is for where statement.
This is a list of usernames:

```
[
  '4feathersandfur',       '4flyman',
  '4iisx',                 '4lergico_',
  '4mygal',                '4mygal',
  '4mygal',                '4mygal',
  '4mygal',                '4mygal',
  '4mygal',                '4ringzryan',
  '4summeror4ever',        '5.by',
  '5.by',                  '5.by',
  '5.by',                  '5.by',
  '5.vt',                  '5.vt',
  '5.vt',                  '5.vt',
  '5.vt',                  '5.vt',
  '5.vt',                  '5.vt',
  '501_f',                 '502_nesha',
  '5050_therealvito',      '50_shades_of_dramatic',
  '50_shades_of_dramatic', '50tonsdesono_',
  '526ha',                 '5588fatima',
  '5588fatima',            '559ac',
  '55sommy55',             '55sommy55',
  '58_q8',                 '5_alsheh7i.94'
]
```

This is a list of new_ig_followers_count

```
[
  '1001', '1000', '1001', '1000',
  '1000', '1000', '1000', '1000',
  '1000', '1000', '1000', '1001',
  '1001', '1000', '1000', '1000',
  '1000', '1000', '1001', '1001',
  '1001', '1001', '1001', '1001',
  '1001', '1001', '1000', '1000',
  '1001', '1001', '1001', '1001',
  '1001', '1001', '1001', '1000',
  '1001', '1001', '1000', '1001'
]
```

I want a single job to update all the rows with those usernames with their corresponding follower's count is it possible to do it in a single job.

Schema of the table is

```
Field name  Type    Mode    Description
username    STRING  NULLABLE    
website STRING  NULLABLE    
description STRING  NULLABLE    
url STRING  NULLABLE    
followed_by INTEGER NULLABLE    
email   STRING  NULLABLE    
new_ig_followers_count  INTEGER NULLABLE    
updated_at  TIMESTAMP   NULLABLE    
IG_alive    BOOLEAN NULLABLE
```

Comment: clarify please how this related to BigQuery - is it BQ table now? what the scema of table and what is expected result. note: BigQuery and mySql are quite different engines so leave only tag that your question is about and remove the other one

Comment: yes, I want to update this in a bigquery table. the expected result is I want to update all the followers count column values corresponding to the usernames in the table

Comment: it is not clear what the schema of your table and schema of output - please provide clear example of both

Comment: schema of the table is 
``Field name Type Mode Description\n
username STRING NULLABLE \n
website STRING NULLABLE \n
description STRING NULLABLE\n 
url STRING NULLABLE \n
followed_by INTEGER NULLABLE \n
email STRING NULLABLE \n
new_ig_followers_count INTEGER NULLABLE \n
updated_at TIMESTAMP NULLABLE \n
IG_alive BOOLEAN NULLABLE``\n

Comment: please update your question with all details - format of comments does not allow to show all needed info in readable manner

Comment: check I have updated the question with the schema. I want to update new_ig_followers_count by querying through the username and I am having array of both the columns can I can update all the entries in a single bigquery job

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210194/discussion-between-full-stack-dev-and-mikhail-berlyant).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have not got a way to do this not in a single job

```
function currentTimeStamp() {
  var dateTime = new Date().toUTCString();
  dateTime = "'" + moment(dateTime).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss") + "'";
  return dateTime;
}

function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function query(usernameArray, followersCountArray) {
  for (let i = 0; i < usernameArray.length; i++) {
    await sleep(10000)
    console.log("usernameArray, followersCountArray", usernameArray[i], followersCountArray[i])
    const query = `UPDATE \`instagramdata.instagram.40_50_followers\`
          SET new_ig_followers_count = ${followersCountArray[i]}, updated_at = ${currentTimeStamp()}, IG_alive = true
          WHERE username = ${usernameArray[i]}`;
    const options = {
      query: query,
    };
    const [job] = await bigquery.createQueryJob(options);
    console.log(`Job ${job.id} started.`);
    const [rows] = await job.getQueryResults();
    console.log('Rows:');
    rows.forEach(row => console.log(row));
  }
}
```

I am able to update rows using this function query for all the usernames in the usernameArray. I am open to know a solution to update all rows in a single job

Answer (score 2):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
UPDATE `instagramdata.instagram.40_50_followers`
SET 
  new_ig_followers_count = followersCount, 
  updated_at = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), 
  IG_alive = TRUE
FROM (
  SELECT [
    '4feathersandfur',       '4flyman',
    '4iisx',                 '4lergico_',
    '4mygal',                '4mygal',
    '4mygal',                '4mygal',
    '4mygal',                '4mygal',
    '4mygal',                '4ringzryan'
  ] AS usernameArray,
  [
    '1001', '1000', '1001', '1000',
    '1000', '1000', '1000', '1000',
    '1000', '1000', '1000', '1001'
  ] AS followersCountArray
),
UNNEST(usernameArray) AS Name WITH OFFSET
JOIN UNNEST(followersCountArray) AS followersCount WITH OFFSET
USING(OFFSET)
WHERE username = Name
```

Comment: can you please explain this query to me?

Comment: sure. above takes those two arrays (usernameArray, followersCountArray) and unnest them - meaning for each array - kind of temporary table being generated with two columns - first column is element of array and second column (offset) is position of this element in array. Then those two tables joined on that position, so now we have table with two columns respective elements from both arrays (user, count) and finally we do update - hope this helped